# Is there a wireless solution with latency below 60us?

Tags: communication, wireless, bluetooth

This is a purely academic question as a part of an upcoming project I'm thinking about embarking.

Earlier this year I made a wireless joystick-adapter for Commodore 64 using an RS232-compatible bluetooth-board. The latency from start to stop was about 6ms if I recall correctly.

For the next project I'm thinking of making a serial bus wireless. While reading the specs I see that some parts of the handshaking requires real narrow timeframes to work correctly. The shortest is stated "max 60us" and the longest is "max 1000us".

So, with some bit-chugging microcontroller involved, is there any possibility - using any wireless solution - to get below 60us? Or should I scrap this idea before even starting.

---

Here's the document "[IEC disected](http://www.zimmers.net/anonftp/pub/cbm/programming/serial-bus.pdf)"  On page 11 are the times I've been reading up on.

Comment: Which serial bus, USB? That latency will be *extremely* hard to achieve, even if you don't have to do retransmissions. I see Nordic Semi are really excited about having a guitar pickup with 2.3miliseconds latency, which suggests that microsecond latency would be some kind of world record: http://www.nordicsemi.com/eng/News/News-releases/Product-Related-News/World-s-lowest-latency-wirelesss-guitar-jack-is-superior-to-a-wired-link

Comment: Scrap the idea. Rather than trying to make the wired protocol work directly over the air -- the assumptions and constraints are completely different -- you should be thinking in terms of a protocol converter that transfers the information from the wired domain to the wireless domain and back again.

Comment: What is your host system, is it a C64 again or something else?

Comment: @TonyM: Yes. C64 using the IEC-bus.

Comment: Wikipedia says of C64 IEC bus: "In standard operation (LOAD, unmodified KERNAL-routines) the serial bus is capable to transmit 400 byte/second using a 1541 and approx. 650 bytes/second using an SD2IEC. With JiffyDOS and a 1541 approx.2.4 kbyte/second are transmitted while JiffyDOS and a SD2IEC achieve 8.6 kbyte/second. The theoretical maximum is at about 20-25 kbyte/second." Famously went at "get out and push" speed for the C64 FDD. Meanwhile, 8.6 kbyte/sec is 116 us/byte and 25 kbyte/sec is 40 us/byte. So are you trying to go top IEC speed? If s/w has to chat to device, it'll be a lot slower.

Comment: Are you trying to make a wireless floppy drive?

Comment: Not specifically. I'm playing around to see if I can make the entire serial port wireless. Be it floppy drive, plotter, printer, anything connected to the serial port.

Comment: Radar would be an example of a low latency wireless system, but legality and modulation/demodulation will become challenges in making a practical "purpose-agnostic" system.  It's not clear that you have a clear question about a well thought out design goal here.  Generally it is much better to do as Dave already suggested and move the data, not tunnel the protocol.  Have a thing on the computer side of the radio link that acts as a virtual peripheral and speaks the legacy protocol, and have it trade data with the actual device by a more radio-suitable protocol.

Answer (score 0):

At the simplest you can send continuously the UART output through a pair of radio modules, like the RFM110 & RFM210. This gives you no protection from interference, but will work in most  situations. If you want more complex acknowledgement and link management it is difficult to achieve such small latency, because most radios need more than 60us to switch between TX and RX.

Alternatively, quite a few manufacturers sell transparent UART over some ISM radio (not bluetooth), but I have not seen the latency specified nor do I believe it can be so small.

Comment: One easy way to solve the TX/RX switching time issue is to use a distinct frequency in each direction, ideally frequencies in sufficiently distinct bands such that a diplexer is easily built.  This would be necessary anyway if trying to tunnel a protocol that assumes a full duplex link, ie, one with a wire in each direction.

Comment: Indeed, a pair of TX and RX on each side can achieve a full duplex link. With some microcontroller management some redundancy and link control can still be insured withing the latency limit.